# Four black wires (two loose?) in ceiling light

Tags: wiring, light

A rose in my 1970s kitchen ceiling became loose (one screw had been inserted right on the edge of the hole) and when I removed it I was faced with a jumble of wires.The green & yellow was attached to the earth terminal in the rose, four red wires were twisted together and still secured to the terminal, as was one black pigtail. Another black pigtail was loose, and two more black pigtails had been bent up into a hook and presumably had never been attached.

Do I secure the loose pigtail into the third terminal in the socket? And does it matter which wire goes into which terminal (one is slightly taller than the other two)?
[image: jumble ofwires]

Comment: It will be hard to tell.  Is this UK old wiring?  One black/red pair should be power/live.  One pair is probably to the switch and the other two pairs to other lights.  The power and switch might also be combined into one pair, power comes from the switch directly.  Too many ways that four pairs of wires can be connected without knowing how they were wired before.

Comment: Are the disconnected ones for fan control perhaps?

Comment: Thanks for your speedy replies. Yes, it's UK old wiring. Lights in the next door room are also not working, but I know (vaguely) about circuits. (The reason that I posted my question in this forum was that Googling "four black wires light socket" took me to previous posts about four black  wires!)

Comment: Guessing wire connections and electricity do not go together.  Can lead to bad out comes.  The hooks seem be have been on screws.  The red/live wires seem to have been in a wire nut, but I thought they were not used/allowed in Europe.  Used wagos or screws terminals.  Almost looks like what you would find in the US.